# .NET: why store Sync Block in every object?

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance, mutex

In .NET, why is `lock(someObject)` implemented the way it is? The way I see it, there were two options to store synchronization info:

1. Global hashtable to map `memory address -> synchronization info`
2. Store pointer or index to `synchronization info` inside every object that could possibly be locked.

In the first implementation, there is no memory overhead for objects that are not locked - they do not get any hashtable entries. However, .NET uses the second implementation, storing a Sync Block Index field in the header of every single .NET object - even those that are never locked.

**What is the motivation behind this choice? What scenarios is this optimized for?**

Answer (score 4):

The CLR has one header word for the synchronization info *and other things* such as the object identity hash code. [It's a multi-purpose field.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150515023057/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx)

But still, your argument is valid: This could be implemented using a global hash table. This would decrease memory and object creation cost for most objects and increase locking and identity hash code costs. I could see this making sense but it's workload dependent.

Also, from the linked article it looks like COM and MarshalByRefObject information is stored there as well. Maybe this forces this data to be included in the object header for performance reasons. For example, *each method call* on a `MarshalByRefObject` has some overhead to check for remoted objects. Maybe someone with actual knowledge can comment/answer on this idea.

More subjectively, I think being able to lock every object is bad design in the first place. Likely, this was only kept for Java compatibility. The whole `MarshalByRefObject` idea is a total design failure as well. (COM interop is OK.)

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the difficulty of getting synchronization right when doing multithreaded programming, another challenge has been the performance overhead of creating the synchronization primitives. Before the .NET framework introduced its monitors with the per-object synchronization info blocks, locking meant creating and obtaining a kernel-mode primitive (critical section or mutex).

The performance boost of each object always having a synch block outweighs the little extra memory overhead. So it's a speed vs. space tradeoff.

Comment: There could be .NET level locks without the ability to lock on any object. I think `Monitor` should have been instantiatable.; `...outweighs...` impossible to say for sure. It *might* or might not. It is a really big memory overhead. If the avg. size is 50 bytes then 8 bytes are 16% decrease in effective CPU cache size.